# C++: Large complete graph storing and pathfinding

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, graph

I am working with a weighted **complete** graph that has up to **5 · 10<sup>5</sup>** nodes. The edges can have either cost **A** or cost **B** (the edges that have cost **B** can be a maximum of **5 · 10<sup>5</sup>**)

What I have to do, is to write a program that computes the path with the smallest cost between node **1** and node **N** (with a time limit of 1 second).

I would like some insight into how I should store the graph since it has such a great number of nodes. I first thought of adjacency lists but they might prove to be too slow.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate but my problem is not the search algorithm, but the way that the graph should be stored.

Comment: The two are inextricably bound up with one another.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? I can't believe this coming up two times in short succession without it being part of some running competition

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29 With graphs, you pretty much get to chose from Adjacency list, Incidence list, Adjacency Matrix, and Incidence matrix. The table at wikipedia shows the computational comparison between them, that should be the driving factor of what you use. tl;dr; It depends on how you use AND build the graph.

Comment: I know I'm an annoying American, but is that 500 nodes or 500000 nodes?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams That's 500000 nodes and 500000^2 edges (of which 500000 have a different weight than the others)